# store local storage value in a PHP variable without POST submissions

Tags: php, local-storage

I want to store the contents of local storage in a PHP variable without having to use a POST. I found this way, but it returns a string whose length is equal to the length of the entire script and the value is equal to the value stored in local storage. It is not used to make subsequent comparisons of the stored value.

Example:

```
$status = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('click_on_menu'))</script>";
```

(local storage contains "ok")

```
var_dump($status); -> string(71)"ok"
```

when you do a comparison

```
strcmp($status,"ok")
```

returns that they are not equal (-1) because string length of the variable is 71

If I cast it to an integer and handle it with numbers:

```
$status =(int) "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('click_on_menu'))</script>"; (local storage contains 1)

I have also tried with settype, intval with the same result
```

It throws me the following

```
var_dump($status); -> int(0)
```

and does not read what is actually stored.

Any solution for this situation?
Thanks for your time

Comment: `string(71)"ok"` I am not really convinced `ok` string takes 71 characters

Comment: I don't think you can send data from client to server without new request to server.

Comment: How can you get result "ok" from the `$status = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('click_on_menu'))</script>"; ` line? $status holds a string which can be outputted in document like `<html>... <?= $status ?> ...</html>` and this would result in a script being run and write the got local storage item as a salt text where it's called in document. So you cannot get the result of this script into a PHP variable. That's the number 1 mistake. This mistake is probably causing the rest of the process to fail. There're other ways to get local storage data into the PHP.

Comment: code <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1luDNrmS69ydD6mUo7AWUakz2WWxin83s/view?usp=share_link">
result <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1slakz1LRlpNVpvJ41SF3-xGdcJkGw-iC/view?usp=share_link">

Comment: ok then i understand that this procedure is totally wrong. I have seen that they do it by making an ajax request through POST, I will try it there, although the problem is having to call another php file again and refresh the page having changed said value.... anyway, I will do tests On that side, thank you very much everyone!